# How to access hidden pictures on Galaxy S4 with broken screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, gallery, images, broken-screen, hidden

I have Samsung Galaxy S4 from T-Mobile, but I happen to break it. I still can turn it on and hear it, but the screen won't light up at all. Now, I have certain pictures. I put them in the stock hidden picture folder within the Gallery on the phone so no one will find them.

I tried plugging it into my Windows 8 computer to get everything off of it (music, videos, pictures, etc.). I couldn't get to the pictures in that hidden folder. Can someone help me how to access those images on PC?

Here is a video link to show you where I hide the pictures and everything:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aWzsLMwG10

Comment: How and where do you hide that folder? If you have file explorer (e.g. [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)) on your phone, can you access it?

Comment: well if you go into the gallery on the s4 and press the menu button on the phone when you select a picture you can hide it and view it later, and i have the normal file explorer the phone comes with but i cant see the screen because its broken so that is useless...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the broken screen on the very end of the post. I cleaned up your post for now.

Comment: Do you usually have to enter a password of kinds to access that "hidden folder"? If not, it's most likely just a "normal hidden folder" in terms of the file system. Make sure all files are displayed, and watch out for folders/files having their names starting with a dot (`.`).

Comment: no you cant have a password on it, but i will try and see if i can display them all

Comment: Ok i tried lookingto hidden files but nothing came up... and i looked for anything that startedwith (.) but still nothing

Comment: How did you get this problem fixed ?